# Weird connection on uv map

Tags: uv-image-editor

[[image]

On the UVmap there are weird connection that is not in the model

Comment: Hi :) Looks like someone merged vertices, and didn't unwrap them again

Comment: @JachymMichal means that you need to reunwrap your model because you probably made some modifications to it after the first unwrap.